# Help identifying a connector for a socket

Tags: connector, identification

I need help identifying the right connector for this port it is for a stepper motor, any help would be awesome

[image: socket]

Comment: Can you provide some measurements (pin pitch, dimensions of the shell)? This will help confirm whether something is exactly right or just looks similar. A caliper is a great tool for this kind of situation, if you don't already have one.

Comment: I have one idea of what this could be... but yes, some dimensions would be nice.

Comment: any printing of the stepper connector?

Answer (score 1):

Probably a standard [molex connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector):
AMP MATE-N-LOK 1-480424-0

[image]